# Drools error with IKVM

Tags: drools, ikvm

We are using Drools engine on our client written in C#. We are using IKVM to convert the drools jar and our java beans into dll's using IKVM. We are a rule similar to this:-

```
rule "aggregate rule"
    when 
        $b : Bill(billAmount > 100)
        $n : Number(doubleValue > 100) from accumulate ( $l : LineItem() from $b.findItems("color", "blue"), sum($l.getSellingValue()))
    then
        VoucherSeries fact0 = new VoucherSeries();
        fact0.setSeriesCode( "aggregate voucher" );
        insert(fact0 );
        voucherlist.add(fact0);
        System.out.println("sum" + $n);
end
```

This rule works fine when it is run with java based drools API's, but while running it with IKVM converted drools, it throws the following error:-

Unable to cast object of type 'AccumulateMemory' to type 'FromMemory'.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This can have many causes. For example a [classloading](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader) problem. It can be a bug in IKVM. etc.

I think not that you will receive a helpful answer here. You should contact the mailing list from IKVM with many details like the IKVM version, how you have compiled the dlls, a runnable sample to demonstrate the problem.

This problem you can only solve if you [debug](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Debugging) it.